# Bash bad substitution with subshell

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I am trying to get the Distro name without the quotation marks.

`cat /etc/*-release | grep "NAME=.*" -o | cut -d "=" -f2 | head -n1`

Returns:
`"CentOS Linux"`

Now, using shell substitution, I tried to remove the quotation marks my placing the command in a sub-shell:

```
echo ${$(cat /etc/*-release | grep "NAME=.*" -o | cut -d "=" -f2 | head -n1)/\"}
```

I was thinking I could escape the quote using `\"` and then omitting the last `/` to simply delete the quotes.

EDIT:
I know this could be done with `awk`, but I don't know how.

EDIT:
Output of `cat /etc/*-release`:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

Expected output: CentOS Linux

Comment: @Inian There is no sample file, these are files under `/etc/`. At least on Debian and CentOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`, getting the OS name following the `NAME` variable.

```
awk -F"=" '$1=="NAME"{gsub(/"/, "", $2);print $2; exit}' /etc/os-release 
CentOS Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/os-release` appears to be a simple set of shell assignment statement; you *might* simply source it and output the value of `$NAME` (using a subshell to avoid potentially overwriting any variables in the current shell):

```
( . /etc/os-release; echo "$NAME" )
```

This might be a security risk, depending on your level of trust that `/etc/os-release` could contain other executable code for whatever reason.

Depending on your actual needs, you might also simply use `/etc/centos-release`, which contains the information you want as a simple string. (You might not be assuming that your script will run on a CentOS box, of course. `os-release` appears to be a more distro-agnostic version.)

Comment: If the file may change you can even say `(. $(grep -l "^NAME=" /etc/*ease); echo "$NAME")` so that you source the file containing `^NAME=`.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution almost works. The quotes in `"CentOS Linux"` were part of the release-file, using a subshell doesn't help. You can use `cut` with a double quote as delimiter:

```
cat /etc/*-release | grep "NAME=.*" -o | cut -d "=" -f2 | head -n1 | cut -d '"' -f2
```

You can do the same using `sed` with

```
sed -n '/^NAME=/ {s/NAME="\(.*\)".*/\1/p;q}' /etc/*-release
```

Explanation: Tell `sed` only to print lines asked for with a `p`, look for a line starting with `NAME=`, match the part between the quotes and quit after the first line with `NAME=`.